# Wordpress query unique post meta - finding all of one value without duplicates for a drop down

Tags: query

My wordpress posts have a city/state combo in the post meta.

I want to create a list of cities with published posts from the post meta.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add the city/state as a tag. Then you could add the tags accordingly to show the required ones for the related posts. You could then use them in your template with:

```
<?php the_tags(); ?>
```

Form more info about tags see the codex page:
[WordPress Tags Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

If you need more control you might consider using taxonomies:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Comment: Jeremy's answer is a good one, and the way you should head if possible. If you absolutely need to continue using postmeta (i.e. it exists and there is resistance to moving it), please provide some more details about the postmeta (i.e. key names, possible value examples) and how you want to display it (i.e. do you want to show a count of posts for each city with a link to posts that have that meta, or just display the info in some way).